# Data fetching for server and client components using NextJS app router

Tags: next.js, internationalization, content-management-system

I have configured middleware to support i18n like the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/internationalization) explains.

Now I am having a problem injecting translation JSON from my CMS into client components, like input placeholders e.t.c.

I do not want the client to constantly spam my CMS for strings every time a site renders, but instead inject them at build time. Or periodically fetch it server side - then have them statically used inside the client components **like they were hardcoded strings**.

This also has to be globally available (cached?) so I do not need to prop drill it down to my components like inputs, e.t.c.

The documentation says that data fetched once will be cached by React automagically but that is not the case when I try it. It simply throws an error that my client does not have the CMS API key, and it only works on the server.

What is the modern way of doing this inside the app router? Hope that this will not be marked as duplicate quoting some legacy way of doing things. Thank you.